# Mysql add datetime column calculated from 2 other columns

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following MySQL table structure:

```
PositionDateTime [DateTime]
Hour             [Int]
```

I would like to add an additional column called BaseDateTime and it would be calculated by taking the PositionDateTime - Hour

```
Example of desired result: 
PositionDateTime: 2015-07-02 12:00:00
Hour: 6
BaseDateTime: 2015-07-02 06:00:00
```

Thanks for any suggestions or sql statement.
Regards,
Bryan

Answer (score 0):

> Use the MYSQL function `DATEADD(datepart,number,date)` where,
>
> `date` is a valid date expression, 
>     `number` is the number of interval units you want to add or subtract &
>        `datepart` can be `hh` for hours,`d` for days, `ss` for seconds, etc.

So, in your case, it becomes:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh,Hour,PositionDateTime) AS BaseDateTime FROM <TABLE_NAME>;
```

More about this function at: [this W3Schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SarathChandra I was able to narrow it down to this sql command.

UPDATE [Table] SET BaseDateTime = DATE_SUB(PositionDateTime,INTERVAL hr HOUR)